# Data too complicated for model to learn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tflearn

Currently, I am working for kind of AI for RTS game (Warcraft III to be exact). I am using TFlearn to teach the model how to play the game by itself. I am gathering data in such a way:

```
[image array in grayscale] = [x-axis position of action, y-axis position of action, tokenized type of action]
```

so, actual data looks for example like this:

```
[[[36]
  [39]
  [38]
  ...
  [12]
  [48]
  [65]]

 [[30]
  [48]
  [ 0]
  ...
  [34]
  [49]
  [ 8]]

 [[28]
  [29]
  [23]
  ...
  [93]
  [38]
  [53]]

 ...

 [[ 0]
  [ 0]
  [ 0]
  ...
  [ 0]
  [ 0]
  [ 4]]

 [[ 0]
  [ 0]
  [ 0]
  ...
  [ 0]
  [ 0]
  [ 0]]

 [[ 0]
  [ 0]
  [ 0]
  ...
  [60]
  [19]
  [43]]]=[1, 1, 35]
```

And it means, that in case of situation shown on image array (in grayscale), the mouse should bet set at 1-x and 1-y positions and the proper action (mouse action, or keyboard press action, depending on untokenized value) should be taken.

Nonetheless, I have problem with proper model fitting. I have 30000 frames, and it seems too little for model to learn properly, because in case of prediction after fitting the model, it always gives out the same output:

```
[1,1,0]
```

I am nearly sure, that's because a low amount of taken frames to learn. I am trying to learn an model approximately 60 actions and changes on screen are not too dramatical, so it's really hard set of data. Nonetheless I would like to ask if there is any way other ways to improve learning of model in such case. I have tried:

1. Decreasing learning rate (to 1e^5)
2. Different activation methods/optimizers/layers amount on model configuration
3. Changing the amounts of actions to learn (i have thrown out move actions from the learning pool for example)

This is how I am acquiring data:

```
import os
import cv2
import mss
import pyWinhook as pyHook
import pythoncom
import numpy as np


def get_screen():
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        screen = np.array(sct.grab((0, 0, 1366, 768)))
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    screen = cv2.resize(screen, (136, 76))
    return screen

def get_data():
    # file names for training data arrays
    file_name = 'training_data.npy'
    copy_file_name = 'training_data_copy.npy'

    # deciding if previous file with data is saved. If yes, it is opened. If not it's created
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        print('File exists, loading previous data!')
        print(os.path.realpath(file_name))
        training_data = list(np.load(file_name, allow_pickle=True))
        np.save(copy_file_name, training_data)
    else:
        print('File does not exist, starting fresh!')
        training_data = []
    # saving data after acquiring 2500 sets of inputs and screenshots
    def save_data(screen, output):
        training_data.append([screen, output])
        if len(training_data) % 2500 == 0:
            print(len(training_data))
            np.save(file_name, training_data)
        print("Frames taken: " + str(len(training_data)))
        index = len(training_data) - 1
        print(training_data[index])

    # getting inputs and screen on mouse event
    def OnMouseEvent(event):
        action = event.MessageName
        screen = get_screen()
        output = [event.Position, 0]
        if action == 'mouse move':
            output[1] = 'move'
        elif action == 'mouse left down':
            output[1] = 'left'
        elif action == 'mouse right down':
            output[1] = 'right'
        save_data(screen, output)
        return True

    # getting inputs and screen on keyboard event
    def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
        if event == 'Delete':
            np.save(file_name, training_data)
            print("Save and exit")
            exit()
        screen = get_screen()
        output = [(1,1), event.Key]
        ctrl_pressed = pyHook.GetKeyState(pyHook.HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_CONTROL'))
        shift_pressed = pyHook.GetKeyState(pyHook.HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_SHIFT'))
        try:
            if ctrl_pressed and int(pyHook.HookConstants.IDToName(event.KeyID)) in range(10):
                output[1] = 'bind' + event.Key
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            if shift_pressed and int(pyHook.HookConstants.IDToName(event.KeyID)) in range(10):
                output[1] = 'add' + event.Key
        except ValueError:
            pass
        save_data(screen, output)
        return True

    # create a hook manager
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    # watch for all mouse events
    hm.MouseLeftDown = OnMouseEvent
    hm.MouseRightDown = OnMouseEvent
    #hm.MouseMove = OnMouseEvent
    hm.KeyUp = OnKeyboardEvent
    # set the hook
    hm.HookMouse()
    hm.HookKeyboard()
    # wait forever
    try:
        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    # looping getting data
    while True:
        pass
```

This is my model configuration:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
import tensorflow as tf

def trainingmodel(width, height, lr):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 1], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.25)
    network = fully_connected(network, 3, activation='softmax')
    sgd = tflearn.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, lr_decay=0.96, decay_step=100)
    network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=lr, name='targets')
    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_training_model',
                        max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=2, tensorboard_dir='log')

    return model
```

Comment: As a very minor comment, you should normalize the input data. Working with [-1.0, 1.0] or [0.0, 1.0] will be way easier than with [0, 255]. (But probably still too hard.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you are trying to do is possible at all using pictures. I have seen this applied to Super Mario Brothers but WC3 is a way more complex scenario. You would need pictures of every move for every character for the model to derive the right conclusions.

Your model probably will not be able to deal with situations that were not shown to it (in a similar way). You could try to extract movements for charaters using template matching and teach the model on (x, y) positions instead of images with CNN.

Comment: Let's say that I want to limit it only to one race. I'm kind of aware that it's complicated, but it would still be too much to teach the model?

Comment: I'd say it is to complicated. The model has to get the basic idea of how the game works. That's way easier with chess or checkers but with WC3 there are lots of other things the model has to learn (many different characters, their benefits, background landscape). And your model has to be aware of the  temporal sequence of images (recurrent neural network).

Comment: You can start easy and see where it leads you. Take a single character and move it across the screen. Then use these frames to overfit your model. Once that works (it should) you might get an idea of how difficult it is to get a model to play it. And of the amount of training data you will need.

Comment: When you designed the layers for your network, what were your ideas on how big the layers are and the order?

Comment: To be honest it was trial and error process. My starting point was layers setting taken from GTAV self-drive tutorial. Then, to fight with overfitting I was deleting layer, after layer and then just give up on configuring them, when it doesn't give out any results to try to know if it's even possible.